# Is it possible to access whatsapp message database history using javascript or python?

Tags: javascript, python, automation, whatsapp

I'm trying to get the chat history of my whatsapp account using whatsapp web. I could actually use selenium and go chat by chat, extracting every conversation (scraping, basically).

Is there any way to access the database where this messages are stored, so I don't actually need to scrape it? I have looked into some libraries, like `whatsapp-web.js`, but I couldn't find anything that just gives me the messages.

Answer (score 0):

For `Selenium` you gonna need first to install the latest `Chromedriver` as a webdriver, you can download it here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

then we install `Selenium` `pip install selenium`

and here could be a python script below, all the informations are in comments, you gonna have to replace the proper variable with the one you want.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Replace "your_phone_number" with the phone number of the chat you want to scrape.
target_chat = "your_phone_number"

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

# Wait for QR code to be scanned
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="side"]')))

# Search for the target chat
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_2_1wd"]')
search_bar.click()
search_bar.send_keys(target_chat)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Wait for chat to open
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_1ays2"]')))

# Scroll up to load more messages (increase the range to load more messages)
for _ in range(5):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
    time.sleep(2)

# Get all message elements
messages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "message-in") or contains(@class, "message-out")]')

# Extract the text from the message elements
for message in messages:
    try:
        text_element = message.find_element_by_css_selector("span.selectable-text")
        print(text_element.text)
    except:
        continue

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: What if the chat we want is a group chat and not an individual (hence no target_chat phone number)?

Comment: Looks like every groupchat has a group-id and there is a way to finding it - see https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-whatsapp-messages-with-python-in-3-steps-d64cf0de4539

Just wondering if this method applied to the code above will work?